# Is a dynamic expression as collection in a list comprenhension evaluated only once?

Tags: python

Is a dynamic expression as collection in a list comprenhension evaluated only once? For example:

```
val_str = [str(val) for val in list(range(10))]
```

Is the `list(range(10))` bit evaluated only once or 10 times?

Comment: How would the loop stop if it was evaluated over and over again?

Comment: it should only be getting evaluated once.  it's basically creating the list, then iterating over the items in the list and putting them in a new list after stringifying them.

Comment: if I recall correcly this was an issue in other programming languages e.g. C++ `for (...; i < <some_expr>; ...)`

Comment: @SkyWalker. That's a totally unrelated issue. Just because the loop happens to share the name does not mean that it has much in common. Python's `for` is more like `foreach`.

Comment: Yes, the expression must provide an iterable. Then, the iterator protocol is invoked on that iterable, exactly the same as a for loop. Evaluating it more than once would be nonsensical.

Comment: it only gets evaluated once, but it is fully expanded before the list comprehension starts. This is a bad idea, although that won't really matter on range(10).

Comment: As an aside, why use `list(range(10))`? Just use `range(10)`.

Comment: Note, here are the relevant docs: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for

Comment: we were saying the same thing juanpa.arrivillaga -- the difference between list(range(10)) and range(10) is more than just syntactic sugar. Iterators can give a huge boost to performance. If the data set is bigger than 10 items, of course.

Comment: @KennyOstrom yes, I understand your first sentence, just not what you are referring to exactly with your second sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer: It is only evaluated once**
Now let's prove it. We'll create a function with a `print` inside it and see how many times it's printing:

```py
def my_range(stop):
    print("my_range called")
    return range(stop)
val_str = [str(val) for val in list(my_range(10))]
```

The output contains only one line eargo `my_range` is only called once.

Comment: And note that this is also the case for a `for` loop. It is quite common to run a `for` loop using the result of a function call.